# Import IP addresses into firewall configuration (Comodo) using regular expression

Tags: regex, list, text, automation, ip-address

I'm trying to import a list of IP addresses (IPv4) into my firewall configuration, the lists are known VPN servers and are saved in a .txt file, one IP address per line with no spaces or formatting before or after each address.

ip-address-list.txt

```
IP Address 1
IP Address 2
IP Address 3
IP Address 4
...
IP Address 2345
IP Address 2346
```

Each number in the address has a series of digits between 0-9.
There are four series of numbers separated by three colon (.) symbols.
There isn't always three numbers in each series of digits of the IP address:

Example:

```
<3 digits per number>          153.225.143.236       [xxx].[xxx].[xxx].[xxx]
<1/2/3 digits per number>      10.123.1.19           [xx].[xxx].[x].[xx]
```

Problem:
Each IP address is a single and unique address per line - I need to convert them in a format that requires each address be copied **twice** for each entry in the configuration file (Comodo):

The required formatting is:

config.txt

```
<Address Type="1">
<IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="23.82.53.58" AddrEnd="23.82.53.58" />
</Address>
<Address Type="1">
<IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="5.187.21.78" AddrEnd="5.187.21.78" />
</Address>
<Address Type="1">
<IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="123.22.14.27" AddrEnd="123.22.14.27" />
</Address>
```

Each IP address entry for both `AddrStart` and `AddrEnd` is always the same one.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

don't know where/how you would automate it, but with powershell you could do someting like that:

```
$ipAddressList = "153.225.143.236 10.123.1.19 23.82.53.58"

$ipList = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[string]
$regex = [regex] '\b(?<IP>(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\b'
$match = $regex.Match($ipAddressList)
while ($match.Success) {
    $ipList.Add($match.Groups['IP'].Value) | out-null
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
}

$result = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[string]
foreach ($ip in $ipList)
{
    $result.Add("<Address Type""1"">< IPV4 AddrType = ""2"" AddrStart = """+$ip+""" AddrEnd = """+$ip+""" />");
}
Write-Host ($result -join "`n")
```